# Move list of tables around

Tags: c#

For example, I have this matrix:

```
var source = new[]
    {
        new[] { "r", "b", "g", "y" },
        new[] { "r", "b", "g", "y" },
        new[] { "r", string.Empty, "g", "y" },
        new[] { "r", "b", "g", "y" }
    }
```

I want to move the empty string to the top position, up first, to create a result equivalent to

```
var result = new[]
    {
        new[] { "r", "string.Empty", "g", "y" },
        new[] { "r", "b", "g", "y" },
        new[] { "r", "b", "g", "y" },
        new[] { "r", "b", "g", "y" }
    }
```

I want to move the empty string to right, if needed to create a result equivalent to

```
var result = new[]
    {
        new[] { "r", "g", "y", string.Empty },
        new[] { "r", "b", "g", "y" },
        new[] { "r", "b", "g", "y" },
        new[] { "r", "b", "g", "y" }
    }
```

Here is my code so far

```
  static void Moved(List<List<string>> list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Elements:");
```

Checking the list

```
        foreach (var sublist in list)
        {
            string empty = " ";

            list[2][2] = empty;
```

Checking the sublist and accessing elements in the list

```
            for (int i = 0; i < sublist.Count; i++)
            {
                if (sublist[2] == empty)
                {
                    sublist[2] = sublist[3];

                }
            }
```

The value in the sublist

```
            foreach (var value in sublist)
            {
                Console.Write(value);
                Console.Write(' ');
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Not quite clear! Is `"r b g y"` is one string? Also please post the desired output as well

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow, please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add a clear question.

Comment: The output that he need is clear. He want the first line "r g y" and all other to be "r b g y". He already said: "I want to the 2 b's to move down and move upper g and y to the left next to r."

Comment: List<string> sublist = new List<string> { "r", "b", "g", "y" };

Comment: I've taken the liberty of making a large edit to your question. Hopefully this is what you wanted to ask.

Comment: Please feel free to edit the way you want or you think is easier as long as the result is that the laters are in desired position. Thanks

Comment: Jodrell string.empty can be anywhere like games. if one is removed anywhere the others that are on top should move down to that position which is empty and so on. Then after that if there is still a gap then is moved to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var source = new[,]
    {
        { "r", "b", "g", "y" },
        { "r", "b", "g", "y" },
        { "r", string.Empty, "g", "y" },
        { "r", "b", "g", "y" }
    };

        PrintArray(source);
        Move(source, new pos() { row = 2, col = 1 }, new pos() { row = 0, col = 3 });

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Move(string[,] arr, pos from, pos to)
    {
        MoveV(arr, from, to);
        PrintArray(arr);

        MoveH(arr, from, to);
        PrintArray(arr);
    }

    // Moves an item verticaly.
    static void MoveV(string[,] arr, pos from, pos to)
    {
        // Gets the distance to move.
        int delta = to.row - from.row;

        // Gets the direction of the movement (+ or -)
        int mov = Math.Sign(delta);

        // Moves an item.
        for (int row = from.row, i = 0; i < Math.Abs(delta); row += mov, i++)
        {
            Swap(arr, new pos() { row = row, col = from.col }, new pos() { row = row + mov, col = from.col });
        }
    }

    // Moves an item horizonataly.
    static void MoveH(string[,] arr, pos from, pos to)
    {
        int delta = to.col - from.col;
        int mov = Math.Sign(delta);
        for (int col = from.col, i = 0; i < Math.Abs(delta); col += mov, i++)
        {
            Swap(arr, new pos() { row = to.row, col = col }, new pos() { row = to.row, col = col + mov });
        }
    }

    // Swaps two items on each move.
    static void Swap(string[,] arr, pos from, pos to)
    {
        string val = arr[to.row, to.col];
        arr[to.row, to.col] = arr[from.row, from.col];
        arr[from.row, from.col] = val;
    }

    // Print the array to the console.
    static void PrintArray(string[,] arr)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", getval(arr, i, 0), getval(arr, i, 1), getval(arr, i, 2), getval(arr, i, 3)));
        }
        sb.AppendLine("");
        Console.Write(sb.ToString());
    }

    static string getval(string[,] arr, int row, int col)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arr[row, col]) ? " " : arr[row, col];
    }
}

struct pos
{
    public int row;
    public int col;
}
```

EDIT:

Correctend a bug (hardcoded from/to) in the `Move` method.

Comment: Not understanding everything that is in the code but the idea, but the problem is when i run the programm there is just a blank screen

Comment: Updated. It now prints the results to the console.

Comment: Which parts don't you understand? I'll try to explain.

Comment: instead of using var source = new[,]. Is it possible to use List<list<string>>. Otherwise the code is working the way I meant. Thank you

Comment: Sure. It was just quicker for me to write `[row,col]` rather then `[row][col]` to show the idea but you could just replace all `[,]` by `[][]` if you use nested lists. You also need to change the hard coded `4` in the print function. The rest of the algorithm will work with any length. Oh, and the first parameter also must be a `List<List<string>>` then.